# Mostrar nome do usuário responsavel por tal ID no html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mongodb

to fazendo um forum bem basiquinho e to com uma duvida bem facil ao meu ver, mas sou iniciante no angular e está me matando.
Ao criar um novo tópico, esse topico cria um ID ou seja cada topico tem o seu.
 No Index existe uma lista de tópicos criados e um botão acessar que leva para um determinado tópico.
Minha duvida é como mostrar o titulo, assunto e descrição do tópico acessado na pagina teste. 
Obs: estou usando mongod e o postman para cadastro dos dados, e a url onde estão os dados é http://localhost:3000/topico/lista

Abaixo o botão e o js

```js
 $scope.AcessarTopico = function(index){
        //$scope.item = $scope.itens[this.id:id];
        alert("o id do cara é - " + $scope.itens[index]._id);
        window.location="file:///C:/Users/Mayla/Desktop/Forum/teste.html?id="+$scope.itens[index]._id;
        $scope.edit = true;
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-success btn-small" ng-click="AcessarTopico($index)">
```

Answer (score 1):

A sua função está fazendo requisiçao a uma nova página, e passando o id do forum em questão. Nessa nova página o ideal é ter uma controller e nela um método que ao iniciar faça a busca dos dados deste forum em específico. Uma coisa mais ou menos assim:

No teste.html

```
<div ng-controller="forumList" ng-init="carregarDados()">
 <h2>{{ forum.titulo }}</h2>
 <h4> {{ forum.assunto }}</h4>
</div>
```

Na controller do angular:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('forumList', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

   $scope.carregarDados = function() {
      var url = sua_url;
      $http.get(url, {id: pegue_id_da_pagina).then(
            function successCallback(resposta) {
               $scope.forum = resposta.data.forum;
            },
            function errorCallback(resposta) {
            }
        );
   }
}]);
```

Comment: No teste terá os itens titulo e assunto e descrição do fórum e cada forum tem um id.

Comment: E estes dados vem do banco de dados

Comment: O método que você mostru está direcionando a aplicação para teste.html! Para que funcione, sua teste.html tem que ter uma controller! E em seu método inicial ter um get que busco os dados desse post do forum!

Comment: Editei a resposta

Comment: Na parte do id, coloquei apenas - var url = 'http://localhost:3000/topico/lista'  $http.get(url, {id: $scope._id}).then( ... seria necessário algo a mais  que isso, ja que no bd esta _id.